# Valgrind aborting with "pure virtual method called" long before the point where the program segfaults

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-leaks, gdb, valgrind

I'm trying to track down what's causing a segfault when I run my unittests.

When I run it through gdb, the program completes the block of tests in question, then throws a SIGABORT with the message "corrupted double-linked list." From the backtrace, I determined that the problem was occurring in the destructor of a global ProtocolType object.

So I run the program through valgrind, and two things happen: one, I get an *enormous* number of errors; far too many to pick through manually. Second, it gives me a different termination message. Valgrind craps out in only the second test case, with the output "pure virtual method called."

I'm fairly certain this has a different cause than my first error, since the ProtocolType class doesn't use any virtual methods, and is not a parent or child of any other class.

Is there a way to suppress the "pure virtual method called" exception, so that valgrind can reach the point where my bug occurs? Or can I generate a backtrace from valgrind's exception so I can resolve that?

Comment: Searching in the valgrind sources, I cannot find any piece of code that would produce 'pure virtual method called".  If valgrind produces errors, it typically means that you have real bugs in your program.  Critical errors might cause corruption. You could add a few of the errors valgrind shows, as this might indicate the source of the later crash. Such errors should be investigated and solved.

Comment: @phd This error is produced by the [program itself](https://godbolt.org/z/PTer3f). "pure virtual method called" means that a pure virtual function is called in the constructor or destructor (where a call is not virtual).

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about this completely backwards. The error you see in release code is the victim of corruption that is occurring somewhere earlier. You cannot resolve the problem at the victim, you need to look at the perpetrator. So start going through those messages.

You are probably right that a lot of them are spurious. If so, you will quickly filter them down into categories. But it's even possible that there's some broken code you are calling an *awful* lot that happens to most often fail in a harmless way. For example, if you have a bug that accesses an array one byte out of bounds, if the array is usually 10 bytes, that's probably harmless because your allocator probably allocates 16 bytes. But if the array size is 16 bytes, ...

Start at the beginning. You don't want to be trying to troubleshoot a problem that occurs potentially long after the execution environment has already been corrupted.

Since these are unit tests, you can debug each unit test separately if you can run just that unit test. Then you know each test starts with a clean environment. But don't ignore any warnings or errors early in an execution run.

Comment: Part of the problem is that each test runs fine individually. It's only when I run the whole shebang that I get segfaults.

Of course, I haven't tracked down every place where I get a segfault. Gave up after about 5 or 6 and assumed they would all look the same. Is it a good idea to find all the segfaults, and run each of those tests individually until I find one that breaks?

Comment: @EamonHeaney Run them individually under valgrind and troubleshoot each one. You will quickly learn which warnings are spurious and which aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Valgrind operates at a much lower level than C++ classes and object hierarchy. It does know how to recognize calls to `new` and `delete` and also C++ std::thread classes, but that is about all.

It looks like you have memory corruption. Just because you see a problem under gdb with ProtocolType doesn't mean the same class is causing the pure virtual call under Valgrind.

As @David Schwartz already said, start with the first error that Valgrind reports, fix that and repeat until there are no more. Quite often a small number of fixes will clear a large number of issues reported by Valgrind.